# What did Gary Delaney say here?

Tags: listening, jokes

Here is the clip: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BJK_yWFR5UM&feature=youtu.be&t=16m02s

He said, "Her mum agrees to help out, just like ...". I cannot make out what he said here. It sounds to me like 'at hart', but of course it does not make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Her mum's agreed to help out, just until I get hard". I'll expand on that if you want an explanation.

Comment: +1 for the offer on expansion (pun intended?)...

Comment: @Dansouper Sorry for a quick follow up question: He said the phrase very quickly and it sounds as if the words are fused together. For native speakers is it normal? The live audience apparently have no trouble understanding it. For me I can only make out 'Just like get hard'. To you, where are the word boundaries?

Comment: @Stephie - pun intended :)

Comment: @Tony Ong - I though about this for a while; it's difficult for me to give much of an answer past 'it'll take time to get used to the accent'. I've been exposed to a multitude of different accents and dialects over the course of my life, and there a very few i have a problem with (thick Glaswegian, thick Northern Irish are the two I occasionally have issues with, as well as very fast thick geordie, even though I'm geordie myself), so it's just natural for me. The slurring of words together is more common with some accents, and some dialects tend toward it more than others